# How to aggregate values from multiple columns from a Pandas DataFrameGroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following data. I know I can aggregate each column to get stuff like average weight or min length. But say I wanted to calculate something like average weight per length for each dog breed. How would I do that?

```
dogs_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "breed": ["corgi", "poodle"] * 3,
    "weight": [8, 7, 11, 9, 8, 7],
    "length": [22, 15, 24, 13, 18, 19],
})
dogs_gb = dogs_df.groupby("breed")
```

To aggregate a single column is simple `dogs_gb.agg({'weight': lambda x: np.sum(x)})` (there's cleaner ways to do it I know), I'm just not sure how to grab other column values at the same time.

I expect data like this...

```
        avg_weight_per_avg_length
breed
corgi       0.42
poodle      0.48
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dogs_df.groupby(["breed", "length"]).agg(np.mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Codle:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dogs_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "breed": ["corgi", "poodle"] * 3,
    "weight": [8, 7, 11, 9, 8, 7],
    "length": [22, 15, 24, 13, 18, 19],
})
print(dogs_df)
dogs_gb = dogs_df.groupby("breed")
print(dogs_gb.agg({'weight': lambda x: np.sum(x), 'length': lambda x: np.sum(x)}))
```

Output:

```
    breed  weight  length
0   corgi       8      22
1  poodle       7      15
2   corgi      11      24
3  poodle       9      13
4   corgi       8      18
5  poodle       7      19
        weight  length
breed
corgi       27      64
poodle      23      47
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dogs_gb_avg = dogs_df.groupby("breed").mean()
dogs_gb_avg.weight / dogs_gb_avg.length

breed
corgi     0.421875
poodle    0.489362
dtype: float64
```

Or continuing from your groupby, we could use `pipe`:

```
dogs_gb = dogs_df.groupby("breed")
dogs_gb.pipe(lambda x: x.weight.mean().div(x.length.mean()))

breed
corgi     0.421875
poodle    0.489362
dtype: float64
```

I would pick the former, primarily because of clarity.